# Firefox addon-sdk : Creating a UI window/addon page for displaying addon specific information

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a Firefox addon. I have already created a login dialog box using panels in firefox addon-sdk. As the next step i need to open up another windows to display some information queried from the internet at the click on a button in the panel after login in.

1. I have already tried creating another panel and calling it (panel2.show()) from the first panel(panel1) but the 2nd panel is destroyed immediately or it's not resident on the screen may be since I'm calling it from within the first panel and it's closing itself off after calling the 2nd panel to show.

So i need to know a way to create the 2nd panel from within the first panel yet keep it out the life scope of the first panel. Or to find a better alternative to load the content page 2 in a separate window.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to open up like a localized html page?

Comment: Yeah that's it. And then using content script, interact with that page. But my first look is at using a panel, unattached to a separate action button. But when i do this, i call the Panel2.show() from within the panel1's event. So the panel2 doesn't display well (it closes immediately after showing). I checked with attaching the panel to a secondary button and then it works fine.

Comment: Check this out, it opens localized html page, very simple bootstrapped addon: https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/xhtml-xul im not sure how to adapt this to the sdk though, maybe some sdk expert can advise

Comment: Yea I'm not sure how to get it on addon-sdk though. I purposefully dropped the option of addon-page, since it's now obsolete. Thank anyways Noitidart

Comment: It doesn't have to be opened from options page, you can open from anything. :) It should be real simple in sdk just as it is in that non-sdk branch